# Modeling asp.net core identity user access

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been looking in how to setup asp.net core identity model, in order to give access to a user to specific data.

For example lets think that we have 10 different stores.

I want to be able:

Have several type of users for example a salesman and buyer.

How could I setup: 
  First buyer to have data access for store 1, 2 and 3.
  Second buyer to have data access for store 3, 4 and 5.
  Third buyer to have data access for store 6, 7, 8 and 9 
  First salesman to have access to store inventory of store 3, and 4.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Alberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AspNet Core Identity doesn't provide ways to enforce data access to concrete data, like a particular store, which means you have to implement this yourself. However, you can describe the supposed access in the identity models:

The default ASP.NET Core Identity models contain a **claim-model**, in which you can define your own claim types, like *role* and *store*. You can then associate these claims to your users:

```
User 1 Claims:
    "role": "buyer"
    "store": "1"
    "store": "2"
    "store": "3"
User 2 Claims:
    "role": "salesman"
    "store": "3"
    "store": "4"
```

(This is simplified, but might be enough for you. One limitation in this particular model is, that a user can be assigned to a store only for ALL of his roles. If a user is buyer for store 1, and salesman for store 2 you run into ambiguity of what data he has access to. If that's a requirement, then you would have to specify the *role per store* in a different kind of claim type)

This doesn't enforce the data-access though. You need to come up with your own filters when doing any queries against your persisted data, whether they be in SQL, Mongo, redis or anywhere else.